# Volatile cast inside of while loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I noticed that unless I use something like a `Sleep(1)` inside of my `while` loop, it will never break.

`while (*Ns::Gl::G == nullptr) Sleep(1); // Works`

`while (*Ns::Gl::G == nullptr);          // Doesn't work`

After some research I would think it's because `*Ns::Gl::G` is changed by another thread or process, this seems likely in my scenario.

So, I tried to do something amongst the lines of:

`while (*(volatile TYPE **)&*Ns::Gl::G == nullptr);` amongst a lot of other variants of that, and all to no avail.

The way `Ns::Gl::G` is defined is amongst the lines of:

`namespace Ns { struct Gl final { static TYPE** G }; TYPE** Gl::G;}`

Does anyone have an idea of how I can turn `*Ns::Gl::G` into `volatile` inside of the `while` loop? `MemoryBarrier()` works but I'd highly prefer to use the `volatile` keyword.

TL;DR - `volatile` cast inside of `while` loop isn't working.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't protect you at all, it's not what the keyword is for. Please pick a language, C or C++ so we can give an appropriate answer on how to protect from race conditions.

Comment: Highly related: [When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading)

Comment: @SombreroChicken This isn't a race condition. I'm waiting for `*Ns::Gl::G` to not be a null pointer, but this never happens, unless I add a sleep due to compiler optimizations. Anyway, either language is fine.

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear: If some other thread is changing `G`'s value, then that *is a race condition*. What is responsible for changing `G`'s value?

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear If it's another thread that's changing that value then that's literally a race condition.

Comment: @NicolBolas A thread inside of a process which I injected myself into.

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear: Then whatever thread is writing the variable needs to synchronize with your attempts to read it. Since you're using injection rather than a cooperative interface, it's likely the writing thread does not expect another thread to be reading it, so no synchronization happens. And therefore, there is no way (within the C++ standard) to ensure the order or visibility of that value. So you'd have to rely on out-of-standard mechanisms, like the side-effects of a full memory barrier (such as you might get out of `Sleep`).

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear: This is not specifically about "compiler optimizations". The CPU's cache architecture must also be appeased. And, as explained in the duplicate, `volatile` does not.

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear Maybe a `yield();` call after checking would be enough than the `Sleep();`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see, that indeed seems to be the case. Thank you!

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear Yes, you have a [data race](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.races) even if it doesn't look like a traditional race. Any time you evaluate something that is also being written to by another thread without synchronization, you have a race condition. Race conditions are not limited to when two threads literally race, where the order they finish matters. You have to synchronize your pointer, anything less is Undefined Behavior and any other fix is a bandaid for your symptoms, and bandaids don't stick well to UB.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ `Yield()` doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I'd like a prettier solution than `Sleep()` but oh well..

Comment: @KaekeaSchmear Since you don't have any control over the hooked process, and access any memory synchronizarion from it, I am afraid you'll need to stick with the _ugly_ `Sleep()` call. Maybe there's some WinAPI trickery to apply _change watchers_ for specific process addresses, I am not aware so far.

Comment: C++ cannot be learned by *guessing*. You should read [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5910058) or two.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ So it seems. Thank you so much!